# How can I create a drop-down menu using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a database collection of documents, and I will like to display them on the screen. I am using bootstrap for my application. How can I create a drop-down menu showing the documents in that collection?

Comment: do you mean drop-down menu?

Comment: It helps to use the docs provided,  see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). In short you do:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```